# Azure devops error 0000000d-0000-8888-8000-000000000000 needs Read Organization resources permission

Tags: azure-devops

I have been using azure devops pipelines for some time but today there is an error:

Access Denied: 0000000d-0000-8888-8000-000000000000 needs the following permission(s) on the resource /Organizations to perform this action: Read Organization resources

I cant find what/who is 0000000d-0000-8888-8000-000000000000 and where to configure those permissions.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant find what/who is 0000000d-0000-8888-8000-000000000000 and where
> to configure those permissions.

The `0000000d-0000-8888-8000-000000000000` is the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement`. You could get it from the Response:

[Get all deployments in the project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-all-deployments-in-the-project)

According to your description, this issue exists from today. And it works fine before.
After investigation, there are some recent events of available degradation of Azure DevOps, which affected these services, please wait for a while and then try again. If you want to know more information, please click here: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/257032220

You could wait for a while and check if this issue still exists, please continue to contact us.

Comment: I have just started to get this same error myself, however the status has this marked as resolved. Is this a new known problem?

Comment: @user3208483, SR, post the error link, I updated it. The issue is now fully mitigated. Our engineers have disabled a feature flag and will be investigating this further to learn from and reduce the risk of potential recurrences. We apologize for the impact this had on our customers.

Comment: At this momment, all is working fine. It was a temporary issue, some more info  in this link. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Access-Denied:-0000000d-0000-8888-8000-0/1507559